# How to search and print the particular from string or json object

Tags: java, android, json, string

I want to search and print the value of jsonobject or string which i am storing from rest API Response.and i want to print the value of details which is `"Application with 'Temporarily in New Zealand' status is not allowed"`

```
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
    System.out.println("The response from API is:"+ responseJson);
```

output and response

```
    {"errors":[{"code":"PredicateValidator","detail":"Application with 'Temporarily in New Zealand' status is not allowed","source":{"source":"/PersonApplicant[0]/ResidencyStatus"},"title":"Application with 'Temporarily in New Zealand' status is not allowed"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)  class to access values from the JSON object.

```
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONArray jsonArray=responseJson.getJSONArray("errors");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.lenght();i++){
  JSONObject jso = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  System.out.println(jso.getString("detail"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but 
'''JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
 JSONArray jsonArray=responseJson.getJSONArray("errors");
 for(JSONObject jsonObject: jsonArray)
 {
   System.out.println(jsonObject.getJsonString("detail"));
 }

I am getting error message in for loop in jsonarray and getjsonString in SOP stattment .

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to JSONObject
The method getJsonString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: Updated code, try now

Comment: @akshay202- Thanks a lot , now it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes of a JSON-object by calling `<json-name>.<attribute>`. Seems like you have a JSON wrapped in a list wrapped in a JSON, so try:

```
your_json_obj.errors[0].detail
```

That gives you

```
"Application with 'Temporarily in New Zealand' status is not allowed"
```

Comment: This is throwing error - as i am unable to use , directly as jsonobject.errors[0].details can you please share the code 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JSONObject` you can use `JsonPath` which is built into Rest Assured.

```
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    JsonPath path = JsonPath.from(responseString);
    System.out.println("The response from API is: " + path.getString("errors[0].title"));
```

The above will get the title of an error. It also only works if there is only 1 error available.